# How can I find the IP of my NTP server on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, server, ip, ntp

I tried to do both of the methods [here][1] to find the IP of my NTP server, but I was unable to do so successfully. In fact, the second method does not list the NTP server. Ironically, I need to find the NTP service to put into the space outlined in the second method. Any suggestions to find the IP of my NTP server would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Additional Information:

- When running `systemctl status ntp`, I get error

````
× ntp.service - Network Time Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-06-08 11:24:56 MDT; 15s >
       Docs: man:ntpd(8)
    Process: 8016 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, stat>
        CPU: 9ms
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: proto: precision = 0.051 usec >
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: basedate set to 2022-02-04
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: gps base set to 2022-02-06 (we>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/z>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/z>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8022]: unable to bind to wildcard add>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 ntpd[8016]: daemon child exited with code 1
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 systemd[1]: ntp.service: Control process e>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed with resul>
Jun 08 11:24:56 mikel-precision-5540 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time S>
lines 1-17/17 (END)```


  [1]: https://www.nixcraft.com/t/how-to-check-ntp-server-ip-address-in-linux/1107/2
````

Comment: If NTP server is installed it your computer, the IP address is the same as its IP.

Comment: @Pilot6 Aren't NTP servers always installed on computers? I just assumed I had one. I tried installing ntp but was unable to.

Comment: NTP isn't default installed for many years by now. You most likely have systemd-timesyncd (which is a service) - the CLI to query and control it is `timedatectl` which for your question would most likely be `sudo timedatectl show-timesync`. If you are on a Server you instead most likely have `chrony` which you can ask via `chronyc sources`. Does that help - if not could you please state on which Ubuntu release you are?